# CSS dropdown menu problems

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, margin

I've tryed to implement a simple dropdownmenu without using links (  ).
It's list based. My list elements-width are with procentual values that all together comes to 100%. My last element breaks out in a new line thats what I dont understand. Maybe it has something to do with my margin..

Thanks in advance.

Here is a link to my code:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjPrK/13/)

HTML

```
<div class="dropDown-menu-container">
<ul class="dropDownMenu">
    <li style="width: 20%;">
        Initiating
        <ul>
            <li>punkt</li>
            <li>punkt</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li style="width: 20%;">
        Planning
        <ul></ul>
    </li>
    <li style="width: 40%;">
        Monitoring and Controlling
        <ul></ul>
    </li>
    <li style="width: 20%;">
        Closing
        <ul></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.dropDown-menu-container {
position:relative;
width:100%;
float:none;
clear:both;
display:inline;
text-align:center;
}
ul {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li {
    display: block;
    text-align:center;
    height:50px;
    margin:4px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 2px 2px grey;
    background-color:grey;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
ul li:hover {
    background-color:lightgrey;
}
li ul {
    display: none;
}
li {
    position: absolute;
    height:50px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    top:0px;
}
li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    top:32px;
}
li:hover li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not including your margins in your calculations

Set your width to `calc(20% - 8px)`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bjPrK/16/

Comment: yeah I think thats it but, there has to be a way to do this margin-independent without using some othere container

Comment: Not that I can immediately come up with

Comment: mhh one last problem: if i build this list elements with javascript / jquery... how would i achieve the same effect? (dom).style.width = "calc(20%-8px)"; seems not to work..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29125/discussion-between-marius-and-toon-casteele)

Answer (score 0):

The total of your element area is the sum of margin, padding and border.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

You must include the four pixels of each margin in your calculation.